# Print in single line with consecutive elements

Tags: perl

So I have an array like this:

```
W,X,Y,Z
-7,6,101,15
-7,6,101,16
-7,6,101,17
-7,6,101,78
-7,6,101,79
-7,6,101,84
-7,6,101,92
-7,9,615,49
-7,9,615,50
-7,10,759,38
-7,10,759,39
```

Now, I want to print a line when W=X=Y and Z are consecutive numbers.

Expected Output:

```
W,X,Y,Z
-7,6,101,15-16-17
-7,6,101,78-79
-7,6,101,84
-7,6,101,92
-7,9,615,49-50
-7,10,759,38-39
```

How do I implement this on Perl?

Thanks,
Art

Here is my script:

```
while ( $output_line = <FILE_C> ) {                                                                          
    chomp $output_line;                                                                                      
    my ( $W, $X, $Y, $C, $D, $E, $F, $Z ) = ( split /\s/, $output_line );                                    
    if ( $Y == $Block_previous ) {                                                                           
        print("Yes\t$Block_previous\t$Y\t$Z\n");                                                             
        push( @Z_array, $Z );                                                                                
        push( @Y_array, $Y );                                                                                
        next;                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                        
    else {                                                                                                   
        push( @Z_array_nonblkmatch, $Z );                                                                    
    }                                                                                                        
    foreach $Z_printer (@Z_array) {                                                                          
        print("$Y_array[0]\t$Z_printer\n");                                                                  

        if ( ( $Z_delta == 1 ) || ( $Z_delta == -1 ) ) {                                                     
            push( @Z_adj, $Z_printer, $Z_printer_prev );                                                     

            #~ print ("pair: $Z_printer_prev-$Z_printer\n");                                                 
        }                                                                                                    
        else {                                                                                               
            #~ print ("$Z_printer\n");                                                                       
        }                                                                                                    
        $Z_printer_prev = $Z_printer;                                                                        
    }                                                                                                        
    @Z_adj               = ();                                                                               
    @Z_array             = ();                                                                               
    @Y_array             = ();                                                                               
    @Z_array_nonblkmatch = ();                                                                               
    $Block_previous      = $Y;                                                                               

    #~ <STDIN>;                                                                                              
}                                                                                                            
close(FILE_C);
```

Thanks, raina77ow! However, this is what the output look like: 
-7,6,101,15-16-17-79

-7,6,101,16-17-79

-7,6,101,17-79

-7,6,101,78-79

-7,6,101,79-50

-7,6,101,84-50

-7,6,101,92

-7,6,615,49-50-39

-7,6,615,50

Comment: I am basically calling these elements from a file and using push when Z is equal to the previous value. But here is what I am getting.                                                  -7,6,101,15-16-17
-7,6,101,16-17
-7,6,101,17
-7,6,101,78-79

Comment: show us your data structure where W,X,Y,Z are stored

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach ([**ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/eN2CUH)):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $prev;
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  next unless /\S/;
  my @numbers = split /,/;
  if (defined $prev && $numbers[3] == $prev + 1) {
    print '-' . ++$prev;
    next;
  }
  print "\n" if defined $prev;
  print join ',', @numbers;
  $prev = $numbers[3];
}

__DATA__
-7,6,101,15
-7,6,101,16
-7,6,101,17
-7,6,101,78
-7,6,101,79
-7,6,101,84
-7,6,101,92
-7,9,615,49
-7,9,615,50
-7,10,759,38
-7,10,759,39
```

I choose not to collect this data into intermediate array, as you did, as the question was simple: print it grouped. The key is storing the value of the last (`Z`) column, then checking each new line against it: if it matches, you print just the incremented value (that's what `print '-' . ++$prev` line for), if not, you end this line (for all but the first case) and start a new one with the numbers of this line.

Comment: Thanks, raina77ow! However, this is what the output look like: 

-7,6,101,15-16-17-79

-7,6,101,16-17-79

-7,6,101,17-79

-7,6,101,78-79

-7,6,101,79-50

-7,6,101,84-50

-7,6,101,92

-7,6,615,49-50-39

-7,6,615,50

Comment: Erm.. no, it's not. Did you check that demo (by the link that I gave)?

Comment: ok, i did not know the demo feature until i tried it. i will try that out really quick! thanks a lot!